# two controllers in a single .py file

Tags: python, pylons, controllers

I've been going through the reddit code and i noticed that they sometimes have two controller classes in a single py file.
eg:
api.py
contains:

```
class ApiminimalController

class ApiController
```

I was wondering how that is done. I tried it myself but i am not getting the proper results. Whenever i add a new class i only get access to the actions defined in the class which is defined the way they mention in the docs.
eg :

```
paster controller <c_name>
```

in c_name:

```
class <c_name>Controller:
```

Can i not define another controller class?
How would i define that in the routing.py?

Comment: What? I read your question six times and still didn't get what you need.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to better illustrate the real question.